# Hibernate, select by id or unique column

Tags: java, hibernate, select, unique

I am using hibernate for Java, and I want to be able to select users by id or by name from the database.

Nice thing about Hibernate is that it caches the result by id, but I seem to be unable to make it cache by name.

```
static Session openSession = Factory.openSession();

public static User GetUser(int Id) {
    return (User) openSession.get(User.class, new Integer(Id));
}

public static User GetUser( String Name ){
   return (User) openSession.createCriteria( User.class ).
           add( Restrictions.eq("username", Name) ).
           uniqueResult();

}
```

If I use GetUser(1) many times, hibernate will only show that it executed the first time.

But every time I use GetUser("user1"), hibernate shows that it is executing a new query to database.

What would be the best way to have the string identifier be cached also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the query cache to avoid the database access when querying by name.

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html